# What's the difference between define and defmacro-public

Tags: scheme, guile

I try to decipher [libctl](https://github.com/stevengj/libctl).

In [base/io-vars.scm](https://github.com/stevengj/libctl/blob/master/base/io-vars.scm), defmacro-public appears.

```
58(defmacro-public define-input-var
59  (name init-val var-type-name . var-constraints)
60  `(begin
61     (define-param ,name ,init-val)
62     (input-var! (lambda () ,name) (quote ,name)
63                 ,var-type-name ,@var-constraints)))
```

I can't find the definition of defmacro-public.
What's the definition of defmacro-public and what's the difference between defmacro-public and define ?

Comment: It's a (Guile-specific) Lisp-style macro. There is plenty of information about Lisp macros on the internets, and you can find `defmacro-public` in the manual.

Comment: I cannot find defmacro-public in https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/guile.html

Comment: Strange – I could have sworn it was there, but now I only find `defmacro*-public` (and a hint that it's like `defmacro-public`). In any case, `defmacro-public` should be the same as `defmacro`, but it also exports the definition from the current module. [This](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/docs/docs-1.6/guile-ref/Macros.html#Macros) is a relevant part of the manual.